# How to ask "Is it because..." questions

Tags: translation

What is the general pattern for asking questions of the form

> Is it because ...?

My most naïve guess would be

> 是为什么。。。？

Comment: You could say `是因为。。。吗`？

Answer (score 2):

In fact this is a sentence that enhances the reason why……? And now you can reguard it in English, something like:

It's because I saved a sick man that I was late for school……

To translate this into Chinese directly, this means：是因为AA，所以导致BB的后果。

(Change this to English in question：Is it **because you saved a sick man** that you were late for school?)

To translate this into Chinese directly, this means：**是因为AA才导致BB吗？**

In Chinese, we always ignore something according to the actual context, and such statement as this always happens when a teacher see that you are late for school, and maybe the student will make a dialog like this:

Teacher: Why are you late for school?

Student: It's beause I saved a sick man (that I was late for school).

Teacher: Really？**Is it because you saved a sick man** (that you were late for school)?

是真的吗？**是因为你救了一个病人**（以至于你上学迟到了？）